# Is the following inequality necessarily true for positive random variables?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a **positive** random variable. Then we know using Cauchy-Schwartz that $E(X^2) \ge (E(X))^2.$ But from several numerical experiments, I keep seeing that $E(X^2) \le 2E^2(X).$ I wonder if it's true? Any hint appreciated!

**Update:** $E^2(X) \equiv (EX)^2$

**Update:** I think it's false in general, because it amounts to $\sigma^2 > \mu^2 \equiv \sigma < \mu.$ I think in my numerical experiments, this particular condition was satisfied for the random variable generating the data, and hence I kept seeing this.

Comment: What do you mean with notation $E^2(X)$?

Comment: @drhab $E^2(X) \equiv (EX)^2$

Comment: But then proving $E^2(X)\geq (E(X))^2$ does not require Cauchy-Schwartz, does it? It is direct.

Comment: @drhab My apologies, there was a typo that's been corrected now: I meant $EX^2.$

Comment: Just a point: $E(X^2) \ge (E(X))^2$ came from the Jensen's Inequality taking $g(x) = x^2$. See more in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality.

Comment: @RenatoFernandes, sure but it can also be proven using Cauchy-Scwartz for integrals of functions for probability measures. I'll look at the Jensen's inequality approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you point in your update, $E(X^2)\le2E^2(X)$ does not holds, in general.

In fact:

$$E(X^2)\le2E^2(X) \iff E(X^2) - E^2(X) \le E^2(X) \iff Var(X) \le E^2(X) \iff \sigma \le |\mu|$$

Where $\sigma$ is denoting the standard deviation of $X$ and $\mu$, the expected value. In that way, $E(X^2)\le2E^2(X)$ holds if and only if the absolute value of the mean is greater than the standard deviation.